# Django model inheritence

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Consider we have a model like this

```
class A(Models.model):
    ....

class B(A):
    ....
    x = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="rn1")
    ....

class C(A):
    ....
    x = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="rn2")
    ....
```

Observe that both fields above define the same thing with just a difference in the `related_name`. I feel that this part can also be shifted to `class A` somehow and just change the related_name in children.

Can this be done or should I use copies of the same code with different `related_name`?

Comment: If it were `ManyToManyField` then your thought _might_ work, but since it is a `ForeignKey`, it is a 1:n relation, and the reverse would not work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

models.ForeignKey() creates a new object from Foreign key class.

Maybe u can do something in **init** but this causes more  code block  and some third party tools like south may give error.